# How can I replace named vars in a string in python from an incomplete dictionary?

Tags: python, cgi, heredoc

I have a long html form I'm retriving data from and then populating in an html document and emailing it.  I'm using form = cgi.FieldStorage() to get the data posted from my form and then I have a string for the message body similer to (but mutch longer than)

```
 msg = """<html><p>%(Frist_Name)s</p><p>%(Last_Name)s</p></html> """ % form
```

Which according to debuging works until it finds one of my named vars that was not submitted with the form.

There are many optional fields on the form, what can I do to either make this work or do something similar so I don't have to gather all the fields beforehand(ie manually reenter each field) and create a blank one if it's None? Or is there no easier way then doing exactly that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set defaults

```
my_data_dict = {'first_name':'','last_name':'','blah':'','something_else':''} #defaults with all values from format string
my_data_dict.update(form) #replace any values we got
 msg = """<html><p>%(Frist_Name)s</p><p>%(Last_Name)s</p></html> """ % my_data_dict
```

or use default dict (this way you wont need to input all your defaults they will just magically be '')

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(str)
print my_dict['some_key_that_doesnt_exist']  #should print empty string
my_dict.update(form)
msg = """<html><p>%(Frist_Name)s</p><p>%(Last_Name)s</p></html> """ % my_data_dict
```

or as abarnert points out you can simplify it to

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(str,form)
msg = """<html><p>%(Frist_Name)s</p><p>%(Last_Name)s</p></html> """ % my_dict
```

here is a complete example I just did in my terminal

```
>>> d = defaultdict(str,{'fname':'bob','lname':'smith','zipcode':11111})
>>> format_str = "Name: %(fname)s  %(lname)s\nPhone: %(telephone)s\nZipcode: %(z
ipcode)s"
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'str'>, {'lname': 'smith', 'zipcode': 11111, 'fname': 'bob'})
>>> #notice no telephone here
...
>>> d['extra_unneeded_argument'] =' just for show'
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'str'>, {'lname': 'smith', 'extra_unneeded_argument': ' just f
or show', 'zipcode': 11111, 'fname': 'bob'})
>>> print format_str%d
Name: bob  smith
Phone:
Zipcode: 11111
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I could do it that way but I was asking if there was a way to avoid that as it's a very long form. That's what I meant by my last paragraph, but it was probably to unclear.

Comment: You can simplify this to `my_dict = defaultdict(str, form)`. (The `update` step is nice for expository purposes, so you can show what happens with `some_key_that_doesnt_exist`, but in the OP's real-life code it isn't needed.)

Comment: Ok I voted you up and you are answering my question. BUT now I get TypeError: not enough arguments for format string any ideas?

Comment: I would asume you are using a naked `%s` somewhere ... I added a complete example I did in the terminal

Comment: I was escaping literal % incorrectly. thank you for the help. Your code works, except the  cgi.FieldStorage() I am using does not contain key value pairs as I was expecting, it instead contains keys pointing to instances of  MiniFieldStorage .